# 98% usage of CPU - simple C# service

Tags: c#, service, ftp

I wrote a simple application in C#. It downloads a log file via ftp, checked whether firefox is running on the PC, changes the log string, uploads the log back to server.

I am running it every 10 seconds using a Timer.

When the service starts, its memory usage is 10Mb and CPU usage <1%. After about two minutes, its memory usage is ~12Mb, but the CPU usage jumps to over 90%!

This is what my app does every 10 seconds:
1) Download log via ftp and store in *string log*.
2) Go through a list of processes running on the PC, and if there if a firefox.exe process, appropriately change the log string to indicate firefox running.
3) Save the log string to as a txt file, read the file to send id via ftp back to the server.

I doubt saving/reading a couple of lines of text onto hard-drive requires so much CPU power.

Any guesses on what might be going on? Thanks!!

EDIT: Here is my whole class

```
class Program : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

    static string myIP = "";

    static void start()
    {
        string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (IPAddress address in addr)
        {
            if (("" + addr[i].AddressFamily).Equals("InterNetwork"))
                myIP = "" + addr[i];
            i++;
        }

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(firefoxChecker); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (5);             
        timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        start();
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
    }

    static string downloadLog()
    {
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://server/log.txt"));

        // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string log = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        return log;
    }

    static void sendLogThroughFTP(string log)
    {
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://server/log.txt"));

        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\logs\temp.txt");
        wr.Write(log);
        wr.Close();

        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\logs\temp.txt");
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        reqFTP.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
        Stream requestStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        sourceStream.Dispose();
    }

    static void firefoxChecker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string firefoxOwner = "----------";
        TerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
        ITerminalServer server = null;

        string log = downloadLog();

        bool diceFirefoxRunning = false;
        bool monsterFirefoxRunning = false;
        bool careerbuilderFirefoxRunning = false;

        try
        {
            server = manager.GetLocalServer();
            server.Open();
            foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
            {
                if (session.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Active)
                {
                    firefoxOwner = session.UserAccount.ToString();
                    string ip = session.ClientIPAddress.ToString();

                    string user = session.UserAccount.ToString();

                    System.Collections.Generic.IList<Cassia.ITerminalServicesProcess> list = session.GetProcesses();
                    foreach (ITerminalServicesProcess process in list)
                    {
                        if (Equals(process.ProcessName, "firefox.exe"))
                        {
                            // change firefoxOwner string appropriately
                            log = updateLog(log, user, firefoxOwner);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            server.Close();
            sendLogThroughFTP(log);
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    static string updateLog(string log, string username, string ffOwner)
    {
                // make some changes to log string
                return log;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for all the inputs!

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on without seeing any of your code. There are any number of performance-killing mistakes you could have made.

Comment: share some code..it may help others to understand your issue.

Comment: How do you handle the possibility of your processes taking longer than 10 seconds?  What if the ftp download gets stalled for some reason, and 10 seconds later, it's not done but you're firing the function off yet again (and again, and again, and again).  You could end up with a backlog of processes all trying to be executed on your system concurrently.

Comment: Cypher appears to be correct. Also this code is interesting. Are you trying to make sure people aren't using company time to look for a job?

Comment: @asawyer: it's a bit more complicated than that, but yeah, it is used in a monitoring tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the timer when you start doing your work and re-enable it when you are done.

You are downloading and uploading via FTP which could take more than the 5 seconds you have set fro your timer.  If you disable the timer before you start and re-enable it at the end, you will poll 5 seconds after the last upload completed.

You may also want to consider upping your polling time to something a little more reasonable.  Do you really need to poll every 5 seconds to make sure firefox is still running?

Comment: Here's the solution to my comment about the concurrent processes. This looks like it might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, that seemed to be a problem.